# How to write the values of a dictionary into a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

This is my Python version:

```
import sys

print(sys.version)

>> 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
>> [GCC 8.3.0]
```

And I'm running on a Google Colaboratory notebook.

I'm newbie with Python and I haven't found any useful example to show me how to write the following dictionary to a CSV.

```
print(my_dict)

>> {'loss': [0.411, 0.115, 0.147, 0.078, 0.032], 'accuracy': [0.996, 0.997, 0.997, 0.997, 0.997], 'val_loss':  [0.147, 0.100, 0.187, 0.065, 0.052], 'val_accuracy': [0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.996, 0.996]}
```

And:

```
print(type(my_dict))

>> <class 'dict'>
```

And I want to get this **CSV file**:

```
loss,accuracy,val_loss,val_accuracy
0.411,0.996,0.147,0.99
0.115,0.997,0.100,0.99
0.147,0.997,0.187,0.99
0.078,0.997,0.065,0.996
0.032,0.997,0.052,0.996
```

The values for each key as columns.

I'm trying with this code (I'm using stdout to see what it is happening):

```
import sys
import csv

w = csv.DictWriter(sys.stdout, my_dict.keys())
w.writeheader()
w.writerows(my_dict.values())
```

But I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

I have changed the last line with this:

```
w.writerows(my_dict)
```

And I get the same error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

And with this:

```
w.writerows(results.history.items())
```

With the error:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'

And also, I have tried:

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
  w.writerow([key,value])
```

With the error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

Another test:

```
for data in my_dict:
  w.writerow(data)
```

With the error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you show an example of how the CSV should like?

Comment: @HarshalParekh I have updated my question with the CSV file format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv

my_dict = {'loss': [0.411, 0.115, 0.147, 0.078, 0.032], 'accuracy': [0.996, 0.997, 0.997, 0.997, 0.997], 'val_loss':  [0.147, 0.100, 0.187, 0.065, 0.052], 'val_accuracy': [0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.996, 0.996]}

with open("test.csv", "w") as outfile:
  writer = csv.writer(outfile)
  writer.writerow(my_dict.keys())
  writer.writerows(zip(*my_dict.values()))
```

Output:

```
loss,accuracy,val_loss,val_accuracy
0.411,0.996,0.147,0.99
0.115,0.997,0.1,0.99
0.147,0.997,0.187,0.99
0.078,0.997,0.065,0.996
0.032,0.997,0.052,0.996
```

If you need the dictionary sorted:

```
keys = sorted(my_dict.keys())
with open("test.csv", "w") as outfile:
   writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter = ",")
   writer.writerow(keys)
   writer.writerows(zip(*[my_dict[key] for key in keys]))
```

Sorted Output:

```
accuracy,loss,val_accuracy,val_loss
0.996,0.411,0.99,0.147
0.997,0.115,0.99,0.1
0.997,0.147,0.99,0.187
0.997,0.078,0.996,0.065
0.997,0.032,0.996,0.052
```

More on [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: What do you mean with "If you don't care about the order"? Thanks.

Comment: I assumed `my_dict.keys()` would reorder, but it didn't. Just in case you need the output sorted, I will add another snippet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting all those `AttributeError` exceptions is that you aren't using the `DictWriter` version of `writerow()` correctly. That version of `writerow` takes a dictionary as an argument, where the keys of the dictionary are the names of the row fields, and the values of the dictionary are the row field values. That means that row `i` of your CSV file (not counting the header), should be written something like this:

```py
w.writerow({'loss': my_dict['loss'][i],
            'accuracy': my_dict['accuracy'][i],
            'val_loss': my_dict['val_loss'][i],
            'val_accuracy': my_dict['val_accuracy'][i]})
```

Since this is kind of clumsy, Harshal Parekh's approach to writing the CSV file is better, though his first approach does rely on Python ordering its dictionary entries a certain way. (Older versions of Python would need to to have `my_dict` to be of type `OrderedDict` for that first approach to work.)